# How to detect UTF8 with BOM encoding in Perl

Tags: perl, file, comparison

I have simple Perl script that does comparison of two files.
Result I write in different files with UTF8 BOM encoding.
To save text in BOM file I do printing chr(65279) into the beginning of the result file. Sometimes input text already contains BOM char in the begging of the text and my script prints one more.

**The question is:** How I can workaround it to do not print this BOM char twice.

See below text of my Perl's code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
use open IO => ':encoding(utf8)';

open F, "<$ARGV[0]" or die $!;
open S, "<$ARGV[1]" or die $!;
my @a=<F>;
my @b=<S>;
close F;
close S;

my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@a, \@b);

my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;
my @missing = $lc->get_unique;
my @extra = $lc->get_complement;

open EXTRA, ">".$ARGV[2]."file_extra.txt" or die("Unable to open the file");
open MISSING, ">".$ARGV[2]."file_missing.txt" or die("Unable to open the file");
open SUBTRACTED, ">".$ARGV[2]."file_subtr.txt" or die("Unable to open the file");

#Turn on UTF-8 BOM support
print EXTRA chr(65279);
print MISSING chr(65279);
print SUBTRACTED chr(65279);

print MISSING @missing;
print EXTRA @extra;
print SUBTRACTED @intersection;

close MISSING;
close EXTRA;
close SUBTRACTED;
```

Comment: Why not forgo the BOM altogether? For UTF-8 it is entirely optional, since UTF-8 bytes are always written in the same order regardless of the endianess of the platform.

Comment: I need this to pass output text files to another application that supports only UTF8 with BOM, if I will pass text file with simple UTF8 encoding - some characters will be distorted.

Answer (score 4):

Strip it while reading file content (in your example apply `s/^\x{FEFF}//` to `$a[0]` and `$b[0]`) and then either add it in front of output when you `print` results, if you really need it, but better yet - don't print it back at all, as it is useless for UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

If you have double BOM, this is probably because one BOM comes from your input. So you should clean up your input before processing it:

`s/^\x{FEFF}/ for $a[0], $b[0];`